# What to do with access token once I have it in thinktecture identity server

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have followed a series of tutorials online and finally figured out how to use identity server with OAuth2.

I am at the stage where I have an access token which has several properties but nothing which allows me to identify who the user is and persist them/handle authorization.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "nothing which allows me to identify who the user is" - what claims are you seeing?

You can use this tool to peek into JWTs:
http://openidtest.uninett.no/jwt